# Selecting a radio button covered by a div element with selenium

Tags: jquery, python, css, python-3.x, selenium

As the title suggests I am having some trouble getting selenium to click on a radio button because it believes that it will click on a div element instead:

**Important Note:**

I forgot to mention that the div is triggered by a javascript function that uses jQuery.

**/End Note**

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (725, 597). Other element would receive the click: ...

The annoying part about this is that the radio button is not a child element of the div, it's size is large enough to over the area where the radio is placed. 
I've tried using:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#exportValuesLabelsCSV3.radio"))
```

As well as other methods of the expected condition class but nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried maximizing the browser window? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the browser window is maxed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to check if jQuery is done fooling around with the page:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            lambda s: s.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"))
```

The executed script returns a Boolean value so:

```
if element:
            csvRadio = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#exportValuesLabelsCSV3.radio")
            csvRadio.click()
        else:
            pass
```

I hope this helps someone else in the future :)